# MessageBox hides without displaying

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an `MessageBox` and init is a `ActivityIndicator` like `spinner`. So to display the **Alert** Failed, i will have to hide the `MessageBox` containing the `ActivityIndicator` and show the **Alert** as shown below;

But, as soon as the `hide()` code gets executed, the **Alert messgaebox** also hides (or doesn't get displayed). So how can i prevent this ?

```
// There is a MessageBox here, and i will be hiding it to show the alert.   

 Ext.Msg.hide();
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed, faileddd');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar bug where I was trying to show a second alert before the first one had completely closed.  My solution was to add a short defer to give the first one time to process:

```
Ext.defer(function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed, faileddd');
}, 1);
```